# Redmine 2.x with gitolite integration

Tags: git, redmine, gitolite, ruby-on-rails-3

Has someone here correctly configured [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) 2.x (I'm using Redmine 2.0.3) with [gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/)?

If yes, how?

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/20591 does mention https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting, which might have gitolite integration (not tested though)

Comment: Yes, but that plugin work only for version 1.x .

Comment: Ok, just mentioning it to be sure. I don't have experience with Redmine 2.x and Gitolite, so I'll keep looking.

Comment: you are welcome :-)

Comment: I'm also highly interested in a plugin that works with the Rails 3.x versions of Redmine

Comment: In response to "aef" The redmine plugin on [github](https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting) by Eric Bishop is probably the nicer (in my opinion) of the available plugins pre Redmine 2.x but development on the 2.0-migration branch appears to have stalled I forked the plugin on [github](https://github.com/zucchi/redmine_git_hosting) and attempted to get the plugin working one morning. The majority of changes I made however have been cosmetic and not particularly effective. The plugin installs and appears to manage the keys ok. However I had issues with getting the repo hooks updat

Answer (score 1):

[Check here](https://github.com/achalupka/redmine_git_hosting).

Below the file list, there's an online `readme` with a general configuration strategy and a long step-by-step configuration section that might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault - [answers that just consist of links to some other page are not generally considered good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) as they cease to be useful if the link ever dies.  Please consider expanding your answer to contain enough detail to stand on its own without the external reference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are currently a lot of people working on "2.0-migration" branches of the [redmine_git_hosting plugin](https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting) originally made by Eric Paul Bishop on GitHub. Currently the most advanced of the forks containing these branches is [the one by a guy called zucchi](https://github.com/zucchi/redmine_git_hosting).

After looking around for some time, I guess there is no production-ready variant of the plugin for Redmine 2.x yet. Given some more time I hope that something usable will evolve out of the current wide-spread development.

Answer (score 1):

I did this plugin, check it out!

https://github.com/jbox-web/redmine-gitolite

This works with Redmine 2.x only

---

I've finally updated Redmine Git Hosting from Kubitron's

You can check out it here https://github.com/jbox-web/redmine_git_hosting

This one is compatible with Redmine 1.x and 2.x.

The differences are :

- a cleaner indentation, the code is a lot more readable like that
- a better code organisation
- Redmine 2.x compatible

Comment: Please amend your answer to explain why your plugin is better than the current state of redmine_git_hosting.

Comment: P.S.: You link to jbox-web's repo but the README in that repo asks me to clone pitit-atchoum's (your?) repo.